# Amazon Linux Nginx Yaml Unable to Connect Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm trying to create a cloudformation yaml template that will create an Amazon Linux server in the current AWS region, running the nginx web server using the CloudFormation helper scripts including cfn-init, cfn-signal and ensuring that the cfn-hup daemon is running and will handle updates.

The nginx server must be running on my server. I also need to configure nginx to use /var/www/html as the location for the website. Template must also have must have mappings for AMIs in all of the AWS regions.

And the template must create a default index.html page in the appropriate location that displays the following info:

- Name in an h1 header and the title of the page
- The server's  public DNS name and AWS region.

Here is the template that I have started so far, but it is unable to connect when I test it. Can anybody help me to figure out what I am doing wrong and what I may need to add?

```
            ---
            AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
            Description: Creates an Amazon Linux Web Server based on https://github.com/widdix/learn-cloudformation/blob/master/lab0-create-stack/demo.yaml, last access 9/6/2017, on https://github.com/widdix/learn-cloudformation/blob/master/lab8-cfn-init/stub.yaml, last access 9/17/2017, and on AWS CloudFormation Sample Template LAMP_Single_Instance template

            Parameters:
              KeyName:
                Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
                Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
                ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
              SSHLocation:
                Description: ' The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances'
                Type: String
                MinLength: '9'
                MaxLength: '18'
                Default: 131.247.0.0/16
                AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
                ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

            Mappings:
              RegionMap:
                us-east-1:
                  AMI: ami-4fffc834
                us-east-2:
                  AMI: ami-ea87a78f
                us-west-1:
                  AMI: ami-3a674d5a
                us-west-2:
                  AMI: ami-aa5ebdd2   
                eu-west-1:
                  AMI: ami-ebd02392   
                eu-west-2:
                  AMI: ami-489f8e2c   
                eu-central-1:
                  AMI: ami-657bd20a   
                ap-northeast-1:
                  AMI: ami-4af5022c   
                ap-northeast-2:
                  AMI: ami-8663bae8   
                ap-southeast-1:
                  AMI: ami-fdb8229e   
                ap-southeast-2:
                  AMI: ami-30041c53   
                ap-south-1:
                  AMI: ami-d7abd1b8   
                ca-central-1:
                  AMI: ami-5ac17f3e   
                sa-east-1:
                  AMI: ami-d27203be   

            Resources:
              EC2Instance:
                Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
                Metadata:
                  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
                    config:
                      packages:
                        yum:
                          nginx: []
                          mysql-server: []
                      files:
                        "/var/www/html/index.html":
                          content: |
                           <html>
                             <body>
                               <title>CloudFormed Server</title>
                               <h1>My Name</h1>
                               <h2>CloudFormed Server with CloudFormation Helper Scripts</h2>
                               <p>AWS Region =</p>
                               <p>Public DNS =</p>
                             </body>
                            </html>
                          mode: '000644'
                          owner: root
                          group: root
                        /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
                          content: !Sub |
                            [main]
                            stack=${AWS::StackId}
                            region=${AWS::Region}
                            interval=1
                          mode: '000400'
                          owner: root
                          group: root
                        /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
                          content: !Sub |
                            [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                            triggers=post.update
                            path=Resources.EC2Instance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                            action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
                            runas=root
                          mode: '000400'
                          owner: root
                          group: root                

                      services:
                        sysvinit:
                          httpd:
                            enabled: 'true'
                            ensureRunning: 'true'
                          cfn-hup:
                            enabled: 'true'
                            ensureRunning: 'true'
                            files:
                              - /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf
                              - /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf

                Properties:
                  ImageId: !FindInMap [RegionMap, !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'AMI']
                  InstanceType: t2.micro
                  SecurityGroups: 
                  - !Ref WebserverSecurityGroup
                  Tags:
                  - Key: Name
                    Value: Amazon Linux Web Server
                  KeyName: !Ref KeyName
                  UserData:
                    'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
                      #!/bin/bash -ex
                       yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
                      # Signal the status from cfn-init (via $?)
                      /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
              WebserverSecurityGroup:
                Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
                Properties:
                  GroupDescription: hello-world-webserver
                  SecurityGroupIngress:
                  - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                    FromPort: 80
                    IpProtocol: tcp
                    ToPort: 80
                  - CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
                    FromPort: 22
                    IpProtocol: tcp
                    ToPort: 22

            Outputs:
              HelloWorldURL:
                Description: The url pointing to our page.
                Value: !Sub 'http://${EC2Instance.PublicIp}'
              PublicDNS:
                Description: The Public DNS
                Value: !Sub '${EC2Instance.PublicDnsName}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what kind of problem that you have there.
Can you provide the problem that you get ?
Please check the list below on your instance.

- check if the cloud init is installed correctly
- check if the path to run cloud init is correct, in your case is `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init`. Because with different OS, the path is might be different.
- `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, check if there is any problem when running the cloud init, including installing package and start the nginx service.
- check is the nginx is running using `service nginx status`, or depends on the OS.
- Check the nginx configuration & Security group configuration of the stack.